# unable to understand how to find end of file

Tags: java

I'm writing a code where I've to read current line and next line. If next line contains some string, I need to delete current line.

But when I do it, once it reaches the EOF, it is showing me null pointer exception.

Below is my code.

```
private static void cleanUpTempFile(File temp) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(temp);
        BufferedReader temp_in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String tempStr, tempStr1 = null;
        int i = 0;
        for (String next, footnotes = temp_in.readLine(); footnotes != null; footnotes = next) {
            next = temp_in.readLine();
            try {
                if (next.contains("pb") && (next != null)) {
                    tempStr = footnotes;
                    tempStr1 = tempStr;
                    tempStr = tempStr1.replace(tempStr1, "");
                    footnotes = tempStr;

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println(footnotes);
        }

        temp_in.close();

    }
```

It is throwing me error since when it comes since, when it comes to end, current line is showing last line and `next` points to next line which is null. How can I sort this.

Also, whenever there is a replace done, and empty line is created, Is there a way that I can stop creating a new line.

I tried adding the below code in my `if`

```
tempStr1 = tempStr;
footnotes = tempStr1.replace("\\s", "");
```

But this doesn't seem working.

Tried with the below code and my console prints `null`.

```
private static void cleanUpTempFile(File temp) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(temp);
        BufferedReader temp_in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String tempStr, tempStr1 = null;
        String footnotes;
        while ((footnotes = temp_in.readLine()) != null) {
            String next;
            while ((next = temp_in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (next.contains("pb")) {
                    tempStr = footnotes;
                    tempStr1 = tempStr;
                    tempStr = tempStr1.replace(tempStr1, "");
                    footnotes = tempStr;

                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println(footnotes);
        temp_in.close();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: change next.contains("pb") && (next != null) to 
(next != null) && next.contains("pb")

Comment: Hi @MohdAlomar, this is working as Expected. But I've a small doubt, changing the parathesis contents does make a difference?

Comment: @Rakesh: It's changing the *order* that's important here, as `&&` is short-circuiting. The `next != null` doesn't need to be parenthesized at all.

Comment: Thanks All :) But there is blank line created after a replacement :(

Comment: You should definitely be using a while loop instead of a for loop here. The loop will automatically break (finish) when it reaches the end.

Comment: @Rakesh but some operation execute the left hand side first,"and" operation need the both sides to be true. so it will execute next != null if it true it will execute the right hand part which is next.contains("pb"). On the other hand if it false it will not execute the right hand side becuase it need 2 true and its already find the first is false so the expression is false

Comment: the empty line you are using  System.out.println(footnotes);  change it to System.out.print(footnotes);  or footnotes = tempStr1.replace("\n", "");

Comment: Have you ever used linked lists? In situations like this, you should **always** check for null condition before using a variable.

Comment: @Tom you are correct, I misremembered `false` for `null`. It indeed needs a `null` verification afterwards. I will remove my incorrect comment from above.

Comment: @dambros But you were right about the `for` loop, I wouldn't use it either. I would stick to the commonly used idiom `while((stringVariable = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)` which reads the line and also does the `null` check.

Comment: Well, this can't work. You have two `while` loops, so the inner loop already reads the _whole_ file and there is nothing more to read for the outer loop. And since you print `footnotes` _after_ the first loop it will obviously pring `"null"`, because the condition to leave that loop is: when `footnotes` is `null`. It can't reach the `System.out` when it is _not_ `null`.

Comment: @Tom , can I use `if` inside a while? like `while ((footnotes = temp_in.readLine()) != null) {
   String next = temp_in.readLine();
   if ((next != null) && next.contains("pb")) {
    tempStr = footnotes;
    tempStr1 = tempStr;
    tempStr = tempStr1.replace(tempStr1, "");
    footnotes = tempStr;

   }

   System.out.println(footnotes);
  }`. But using so is skipping my first match.

Comment: Your problem is not the `if` inside the `while`, your problem is the content inside that `if`, because it looks very wrong. For example this: `tempStr = tempStr1.replace(tempStr1, "");`. What is the purpose of that line? You have `tempStr1` and your replace the content of `tempStr1` from that with `""`. It is very obivous, that this will remove the whole String to an empty String. Is this really what you want there?

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Baldurian you can check this by using [`Scanner#hasNextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
String prevLine = input.nextLine();
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    String nextLine = input.nextLine();
    //do some stuff
    prevLine = nextLine;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you've tried to achieve with `"\"" + filename + "\""`, but since this is most likely incorrect I removed it. It is also always a good idea to add a link to used methods, so others can easily check what that method does. I did that for you.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your suggestions. I am new to giving answers so still need to learn a lot in giving proper answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Along with checking if the file exists and appending to it if so you should also have a .hasNextLine() conditional.

Comment: He uses `FileReader` and `BufferedReader`, there is no `hasNextLine` to call.